# What exactly are the requirements for the "written invitation" from a family member or friend required for entering Sweden without a visa?

Tags: visa-free-entry, sweden

Looking at Migrationsverket's article about entering Sweden without a visa, it states that if you don't fulfil the 450 SEK per day requirement, you can alternatively provide a "a written invitation from your family member or friend that you will be staying with"[1](https://www.migrationsverket.se/English/Private-individuals/Visiting-Sweden/If-you-do-not-need-a-visa-to-travel-to-Sweden.html). What's not clear from the article is what a "written invitation" actually entails. As such,  I would like to know, what exactly is required from this written invitation? Is a text message on a messaging service enough, or does it need to be a printed formal letter? What should the contents of the text be?

Comment: From the way similar countries do it, I would expect the letter to contain your name and contact details, their name and contact details, where you will be staying, and their statement that they will cover your cost of living/housing while you are visiting. I don't know if a digital message will do today, but a decade ago it wasn't enough.

Comment: Are you flying directly to Sweden?  @o.m. do the Swedish authorities routinely examine the finances of visa-exempt travelers?

Comment: @phoog Yes, flying directly to Sweden.

Comment: @phoog, that's why I made a comment and not an answer. I can talk about some other Schengen countries. Spot checks happen.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The form and instructions on how to use it are available here: https://www.migrationsverket.se/download/18.5e83388f141c129ba631285c/1666876596848/241011_Inbjudan_en.pdf

The invitation form covers eg the personal details of the individual issuing the invitation and their relationship with the applicant, the proposed itinerary and financial details of the visit, and the applicant’s details.

Non-visa nationals who don’t fulfil the 450SEK per day requirement and need to be able to demonstrate adequate subsistence at the border *if asked*, may carry the invitation form or an equivalent (eg a letter covering the same topics as the form) with them.

The person issuing the invitation must send the completed form together with the required attachments by mail or scan them and send them via email to their relative or friend abroad.

Visa nationals must submit the form with its attachments together with their application for Schengen visa.

Comment: Isn't this intended for someone applying for a Visa? As specified in the question, I am asking about visa-free entry. Let me know if I'm misunderstanding something.

Comment: @Newbyte Answer amended to reflect usage of the form (or an equivalent) for visa-free nationals.

Comment: @Newbyte in my experience, non-visa nationals are rarely asked for such details, but in theory they can be asked.  On top of this, my experience is over 20 years in the past and only covers other Schengen countries, not Sweden.  If a non-visa national is asked for justification of the visit, the requirements are essentially the same as for a visa application, though presumably border officers are likely to recognize that travelers may not think to bring comprehensive documentation with them.  It could be that a phone call to your host would suffice.

Comment: Just to add to the legitimacy of this answer, the border control did accept this form as enough to let someone stay here for 80 days.