# Can I provide a written invitation for someone who will stay with me in Sweden country if they are arriving through Denmark?

Tags: schengen, visa-free-entry, sweden, denmark, invitation-letters

When entering Sweden directly through an airport such as Arlanda, there's an [option to provide a "written invitation" in case the person does not fulfil the monetary entry requirements](https://travel.stackexchange.com/a/180662) of a certain amount of money per day. However, due to some circumstances, the person who will stay with me is arriving via Copenhagen Airport (Kastrup) in Denmark to then transfer to Sweden by train right away without staying in Denmark overnight. As such, they will have to go through the Schengen border control in Denmark.

Is it possible for me as a Swedish citizen to provide a written invitation in a situation like this, or do they need to fulfil the monetary requirements Denmark has set? If I can provide a written invitation, is there any form to fill in or other guidance I could use in this situation?

Comment: The way it should work in theory is that the Danish border officer should judge the financial requirements of a visitor in Sweden, and your attestation of support should be taken into account because it will reduce the visitor's financial burden.  I do not know how it would work in practice, though, nor do I know whether a Danish officer would enforce a precise monetary requirement set by Sweden (or even know what it is).  But even if they enforce an amount set by Denmark, your attestation should be taken into account.